# jQuery - Dynamic table rows don't work in IE/Opera

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamic, html-table

**Example (works in Firefox):**
http://progamonth.com/files/tablestestfile.html

I can't get select elements to dynamically get added to a table. This works in Firefox, but it fails in IE and Opera. What's going on here?

DOM code:

```
<table id = "myTable">
<thead>
<tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>
<select id = "select1" class = "hidden">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<select id = "select2" class = "hidden">
<option>A</option>
<option>B</option>
<option>C</option>
</select>

Javascript:

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myTable tbody').append(generate());
});

function generate()
{
  var $row = $('<tr>');

    var selects = [$('#select1'),
                   null,
                   $('#select2')];

    for( var i in selects )
    {
        var $td = $('<td></td>');

        if( selects[i] != null )
        {
            var $select = selects[i].clone().show().removeAttr("id");

            $select.find('option:first').before($('<option>'));
            $select.val("");
            $td.append($select);
        }

        $row.append($td);
    }

    return $row;
}
```

Comment: What goal are you trying to accomplish with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried your code. It seems, in IE, the display property set in 'hidden' css class(display:none) is not getting overridden eventhough you have called show(). Either removing the css class for the cloned select elements or explicitly setting the 'display' property to 'block'/'inline' works:

```
$select.removeClass('hidden');
```

(or)

```
$select.css({display:'block'});
```